# SSIS How to extract files names of multiple folders using a Foreach Loop Container?

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I try through SSIS to extract the names of the files contained within the folder names and load into a SQL Server table. The folders names are already stored in an SSIS package variable.

I'd like to use a Foreach Loop Container that (for each iteration);
 
1) Take one folder name (stored in the object variable) in input.
2) Read all the files names of the folder.
3) Load the files names to a SQL Server destination table.

Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You said you have the directories in a object variable.

1. Add a foreach loop (choose ADO Object) and set variable to a string variable called targetDirectory
2. Add a data flow
3. Add a script component source
4. Add an output called fileName as type string
5. Pass in variable targetDirectory as read
6. Add the following code to CreateOuputRows

   ```
   foreach(string fName in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Variables.targetDirectory))
   {
      Output0Buffer.AddRow();
      Output0Buffer.fileName = fname;
   }
   ```
7. Continue data flow to your destination.

Reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

It's not working.

"The name "OutputBuffer" does not exist in the current context.

Comment: sorry it is Output0Buffer. I just typed all this out without SSIS.

Comment: Let me actually provide a full SSIS example of using a double foreach

Comment: Ok thanks. What do you mean by "it is Output0Buffer"? In my C# program, It mentions that Output0Buffer does not exist in the context.

Comment: Did you do Step 4?

Comment: Did you rename the output to something other than Output0?

Comment: By descending, I have the terms Output 0 - Output Columns and fileName (DataType String  / Lenght 256 CodePage 1252)

Answer (score 0):

My other answer is just fine and would be closer to the way I would do it completely in C#.

However, in SSIS you can do it with just objects provided:

[image]

Comment: In your first ForEach:
Collection -> Enumerator : Foreach ADO Enumerator ? (right) + Expression : What do you write ? + ADO Object Source Variable : ?
Variables Mappings : ? |||||

In your second ForEach (sub For Each)
Collection -> Enumerator : Foreach ADO Enumerator ? (is it right?) + Expression : What do you write ? + ADO Object Source Variable : ?
Variables Mappings : ?

Comment: Your two foreach loops are as Foreach ADO Enumerator?

Comment: 1st one is ADO object based on your object variable. The second is for each file cased on an expresion for folder based on variable from foreach #1.

Comment: thanks. i share the pictures on the post. can you please tell me if it's correct or not?

Comment: 1) In the first For Each , I put Foreach ADO Enumerator then expresion : nothing (blank) and ADO Object source variable at FolderList (variable type Object that contains all the directories). Variables Mappings : User::FolderCurrent and Index at 0. Is it correct?

Comment: 2) In the second For Each, I put Foreach File Enumerator, Expression : Property at Directory and Expression at @[User::FolderCurrent] (variable type string). Enumerator Configuration : Folder at BLANK and Files at *.* and Fully Qualified. Then Variables Mappings : @UserFile Name and Index at 0. Is it correct ?